# map customer and account data to a case class using spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

So I have a case class customer data and a case class account data as follows:

```
case class CustomerData(
                      customerId: String,
                      forename: String,
                      surname: String
                    )
 case class AccountData(
                      customerId: String,
                      accountId: String,
                      balance: Long
                    )
```

I need to join these two to get them to form the following case class:

```
case class CustomerAccountOutput(
                                customerId: String,
                                forename: String,
                                surname: String,
                                //Accounts for this customer
                                accounts: Seq[AccountData],
                                //Statistics of the accounts
                                numberAccounts: Int,
                                totalBalance: Long,
                                averageBalance: Double
                              )
```

I need to show that if null is appearing in accountsId or balance thennumber of accounts is 0, total balance as null and avg balance also as null. replacing the null with 0 is also accepted.

The final result should be something like this:

```
+----------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+
|customerId|forename   |surname |accounts                                                             |numberAccounts|totalBalance|averageBalance   |
+----------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+
|IND0113   |Leonard    |Ball    |[[IND0113,ACC0577,531]]                                              |1             |531         |531.0            |
|IND0277   |Victoria   |Hodges  |[[IND0277,null,null]]                                                |0             |null        |null             |
|IND0055   |Ella       |Taylor  |[[IND0055,ACC0156,137], [IND0055,ACC0117,148]]                       |2             |285         |142.5            |
|IND0129   |Christopher|Young   |[[IND0129,null,null]]                                                |0             |null
```

I have already got the two case classes to join and here is the code:

```
val customerDS = customerDF.as[CustomerData]
  val accountDS = accountDF.withColumn("balance",'balance.cast("long")).as[AccountData]
  //END GIVEN CODE

val customerAccountsDS = customerDS.joinWith(accountDS,customerDS("customerID") === accountDS("customerID"),"leftouter")
```

How do i go about getting the above result? I am **NOT** allowed to use the **"spark.sql.function._"** library at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it by using `concat_ws` and `collect_list` functions in spark.

```
//Creating sample data
case class CustomerData(
                      customerId: String,
                      forename: String,
                      surname: String
                    )
 case class AccountData(
                      customerId: String,
                      accountId: String,
                      balance: Long
                    )
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val customercolumns = Seq("customerId","forename","surname")
val acccolumns = Seq("customerId","accountId","balance")
val custdata = Seq(("IND0113", "Leonard","Ball"), ("IND0277", "Victoria","Hodges"), ("IND0055", "Ella","Taylor"),("IND0129","Christopher","Young")).toDF(customercolumns:_*).as[CustomerData]
val acctdata = Seq(("IND0113","ACC0577",531),("IND0055","ACC0156",137),("IND0055","ACC0117",148)).toDF(acccolumns:_*).as[AccountData]
val customerAccountsDS = custdata.join(acctdata,custdata("customerID") === acctdata("customerID"),"leftouter").drop(acctdata.col("customerId"))
// get the total balance, number of accounts, avg balance by aggregating based on group by columns.
val totalBalanaceDF = customerAccountsDS.groupBy("customerId","forename","surname").agg(sum("balance").alias("totalBalance"), avg("balance").alias("averageBalance"), count("accountId").alias("numberAccounts"))

val result = customerAccountsDS.withColumn("accounts", concat_ws(",", $"customerId", $"accountId",$"balance"))
// Creating a accounts array column by aggregating based on group by columns.
val finalresult = result.groupBy("customerId","forename","surname").agg(collect_list($"accounts").alias("accounts"))
//  Join the finalresult and totalBalanaceDF to get the ectual output needed based on the unique columns.
val finaldf = finalresult.join(totalBalanaceDF, Seq("customerId","forename","surname"), "inner")
display(finaldf)
```

You can see the output as below :
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help but how do you deal with nulls? also I need to show total accounts, total balance and avg balance when null is present? Refer the sample output in the question. Also all of this needs to be mapped to the CustomerAccountsOutput case class.

Comment: Ignore the totals, I got them working but yeah mapping to the case class is where I am getting an error

Comment: Update: I have been told that i should not use agg, sum avg which is spark sql and instead use sparkscala functions

Comment: @codeNoob0101 you could also use agg,sum,and avg on dataframe columns and that does not mean spark sql.

Comment: Your solution still does not help me map it to the output case class and I am kinda struggling using the dataframe operations.

Comment: I am not allowed to use the "spark.sql.functions._" library. You got any solution on that? I am stuck with this and its confusing me alot